# Should I add a resistor to the RCA Outputs of my device?

Tags: audio, circuit-design

Very simple question I just can't find any information about that is not someones opinion or "what their ears think sounds best"

When getting the Line output from my final Opamps to the RCA Jack, should I add some small resistors to its output? Is this actually beneficial like this?
If it is (or not), can anyone explain the reasoning behind this?

Thanks!

My schematic of the RCA Jack:
[image: RCA Jack Schematic]

Answer (score 1):

Looks sane.

The resistors isolate the opamp from the cable capacitance which can otherwise cause instability by upsetting the phase of the feedback.

Generally somewhere in the 50 ohms to maybe 1k is used.

Comment: Next to the good Dan's answer I'd just move TVS diodes "inside", to the board circuits, not on the plug alone. You don't need to clamp what's on the cable but what your internally circuit sees. You also improve clamping a lot due the current limiting effect of resistors .